# Discrepancy in the Imperium of Man's attitude towards STCs

Tags: warhammer-40k

Why are Standard Template Constructs (STCs) not considered heretical by the Imperium?

An STC is a store of knowledge from the dark age of technology, that is operated by an artificially intelligent computer. These are obviously very valuable as it may contain useful technology, especially military technology. Although the Imperium is very opposed to AI. Why does the Imperium actively seek out these STCs then?

It may be one of the following reasons:

1. I haven't read any reference to the STCs having artificial general intelligence/true intelligence.
2. The pros of finding an STC simply outweigh the cons.

Comment: The term STC gets used to refer to two different things in Warhammer. There isTranslate "Artificial Intelligence" to "Machine Spirit" and everything is fine.

Comment: It's also important to note that, when found, these relics are very closely guarded by the Adeptus Mechanicus. They're not allowed to just exist out there in the general public. I guess a contemporary analogue would be Special Nuclear Materials - recognised as a useful and powerful resource, but closely guarded by governments and not allowed to be owned/traded by the general population.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### An [STC](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Standard_Template_Construct) is not really AI.

You may ask an STC a question: *How do I build this...?* and if it has the answer, it will give it to you. But it's not really intellegent and it's certainly not sentient.

> A complete, functioning STCs system was an evolved computer designed to provide construction details for human colonists, enabling them to build efficient shelters, generators and transports without any prior knowledge and using almost any locally available materials. **For example, the user simply asked how to build a house or a tractor and the computer would supply all the necessary plans**.